# Bulma Carousel - make arrows larger

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, bulma

How can you make the arrows on the side much larger (so they'll be impossible to miss)?

[image: bulma carousel image]

Comment: Did you look at what classes were applied and increase it with your styles?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @epascarello, I looked into the styles used for these, and the following does the work:

```
.slider-navigation-previous {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.slider-navigation-next {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Or any other size than `80px` for whatever size you want it